# Different styles for an element based on the current anchor

Tags: html, css, anchor, href, target

In my index.html, i have 3 links that work as anchors. And i also have a div element with a fixed position.

```
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#2">2</a>
<a href="#3">3</a>

<div></div>
```

How can I customize the div element based on the current href? With "id" and "target" I can do this for only two hrefs. For example: on the first page the element was red, on the second page it became green and on the third page it became blue. Is this possible?

Comment: Show what have you tried so far. Use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [SO Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. If you listen to the `onhashchange` event you can then change you DOM to match your requirements.

Here is a working example:

```js
window.onhashchange = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('bar');
  switch (window.location.hash) {
    case '#1':
      el.className = 'red';
      break;
    case '#2':
      el.className = 'green';
      break;
    case '#3':
      el.className = 'blue';
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#bar {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#2">2</a>
<a href="#3">3</a>

<div id="bar"></div>
```